# In AWS Ubuntu, python process stopped itself when running in background with &

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, background-process

command to start python process:

```
python /root/serverFiles/Cusp.py 8001 >> /root/log/cusp.log 2>&1 &
```

Cusp.py is a python code to call a bio-sequence process tool and return result. all the python code and bio-sequence tools are under "/root" directory.

i run it last night, the code test was fine. this morning i checked the Cust.py process has stopped.

i checked it with `ps aux` command, it showed result as following:

```
> USER     PID    %CPU %MEM   VSZ   RSS TTY    STAT START   TIME COMMAND
> root     685    0.0  0.1  12932   912 tty5   Ss+  Mar01   0:00 /sbin/getty
> root     690    0.0  0.1  12932   912 tty2   Ss+  Mar01   0:00 /sbin/getty 
> root     691    0.0  0.1  12932   908 tty3   Ss+  Mar01   0:00 /sbin/getty 
> root     693    0.0  0.1  12932   912 tty6   Ss+  Mar01   0:00 /sbin/getty 
> root     696    0.0  0.1   4328   640 ?      Ss   Mar01   0:00 acpid -c /et 
> root     700    0.0  0.1  19112   904 ?      Ss   Mar01   0:07 cron 
> daemon   702    0.0  0.0  16908   364 ?      Ss   Mar01   0:00 atd 
> root     741    0.0  0.1  12932   900 tty1   Ss+  Mar01   0:00 /sbin/getty 
> whoopsie 743    0.0  0.4 187588  2544 ?      Ssl  Mar01   0:00 whoopsie 
> root     15285  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?      S    08:11   0:00 [flush-202:1 
> root     15553  0.0  0.5  73360  3548 ?      Ss   08:16   0:00 sshd: ubuntu 
> ubuntu   15634  0.0  0.2  73360  1672 ?      S    08:16   0:00 sshd: ubuntu 
> ubuntu   15635  2.2  1.2  24892  7328 pts/0  Ss   08:16   0:00 -bash 
> root     15733  0.0  0.2  41904  1760 pts/0  S    08:16   0:00 sudo -i 
> root     15734  1.4  0.6  21468  3988 pts/0  S    08:16   0:00 -bash 
> root     15785  0.0  0.2  16880  1256 pts/0  R+   08:17   0:00 ps aux
```

would anyone recognize anything from the results above?

additional info: yesterday i deleted the whole "/root" directory by accident, i reinstalled the code and bio-tools.

thanks in advance for any advise.

Answer (score 0):

problem fixed by adding "**nohup**" in front of a command,

for my command:

```
> nohup python /root/serverFiles/Cusp.py 8001 >> /root/log/cusp.log 2>&1 &
```